# A compact set with converging sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that we have a compact set such that it is contained in (0, infinity), Can I find a sequence in the compact set that converges to 0?

Would a counterexample be a sequence in the compact set that converges to 0, is contained in (0, infinity) but is not in the compact set?

For example, $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to 0 and is in (0, infinity) however, since it doesn't contain its endpoint (0), the set is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't find such a sequence if you mean compact sets of $\mathbb{R}$ contained in $(0,\infty)$. In $\mathbb{R}$, compact sets are closed. Hence, the limit of a convergent sequence in a compact set must be in the set.